# Can I create tabbed divs without ability to edit code in <head> </head>?

Tags: javascript, css, html, tabs

I need to add tabbed divs to page, which would look something like this:
[image]

Is it posible to create something like that without ability to edit code inside  tags? If yes, maybe any suggestions or examples?

Comment: Not really, it's not in page and I cant add it..

Comment: yes it is possible. please share your code in jsfiddle.

Comment: naresh, here is all page: https://www.dropbox.com/s/37zxfj90cm8rszh/tabshtml.htm you can see that tabs hing is not showing properly, but it's other problem, now I need generaly to make them apear and disapear when certain (Postage, Returns or Payment) link is pushed. P.s. all css is in style atribute, because on uploading I will be able to upload only <body> ... </body>